# Flutter upgrade issue with lots of un-understandable logs (no harm though)

Tags: flutter

I just upgraded flutter and right after the upgrade I am getting quite a bunch of logs in the console, which don't make sense to me, tried to surf the internet for such sort of errors but apparently there don't seem to be any traces of these kind of errors: For a start, you guys can help me in trying to understand these and how to go about this because it is getting to be quite hard to debug: I must also mention though that the they don't stop the app from running:

```
I/HwPhoneWindow(25343): updateLayoutParamsColor false mSpecialSet=true, mForcedNavigationBarColor=true, navigationBarColor=ff6451fe, mNavBarShow=true, mIsFloating=false
I/HwPhoneWindow(25343): updateLayoutParamsColor false mSpecialSet=true, mForcedNavigationBarColor=true, navigationBarColor=ff6451fe, mNavBarShow=true, mIsFloating=false 
V/InputMethodManager(25343): Reporting focus gain, without startInput
V/InputMethodManager(25343): Reporting focus gain, without startInput
```

Similarly whenever I get the following when I touch anywhere on the screen:

```
W/HiTouch_PressGestureDetector(25343): Touch pointer move a lot. The moving distance of X is:2.0, limit is:51The moving distance of Y is:69.0, limit is:51

Below log also just appears am currently not sure of what is triggering this yet:
W/InputMethodManager(25343): startInputReason = 8
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25343): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25343): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25343): requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe(25343): stop checker.
W/libEGL  (25343): EGLNativeWindowType 0x755f41b010 disconnect failed
D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity](25343): surface should not be released
D/FlutterView(25343): Detaching from a FlutterEngine: 
io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@486f178
W/InputMethodManager(25343): startInputReason = 3
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25343): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25343): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25343): requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
W/libEGL  (25343): EGLNativeWindowType 0x75660d7010 disconnect failed
V/ActivityThread(25343): Handle window ActivityRecord{d450bd5 token=android.os.BinderProxy@c9b5ecf{com.example.cmed/com.example.cmed.MainActivity}} visibility: false
D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe(25343): Current Activity:false
D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe(25343): not watching, wait.
E/        (25343): [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0008]
```

Comment: Whoever is looking at this, apparently filtering flutter logging is missing in `v1.12.13+hotfix.8`. An issue raise from github https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50628.

Answer (score 0):

As I'd earlier stated in the comments, there is an issue with flutter `v1.12.13+hotfix.8`. The issue is currently not resolved yet but you can work around the problem as of now by downgrading:

```
run:

flutter version v1.12.13+hotfix.7
```

This is because hotfix.8 is missing log filters